How to get the second row of each duplicate values only in SQL Server?
How to get the second row of each duplicate values ?



id
name
email




1
John
John-email


**2
John
John-email**


3
Mac
mac-email


**4
Mac
mac-email**


5
Son
son-email


**6
Son
son-email**


**7
Son
son-email**


8
Son
son1-email



Let say this was my table, So what I want from the result is only to show only rows number :
2,4,6,7 because that was the duplicates values which is exclude the first value of each rows.



id
name
email




**2
John
John-email**


**4
Mac
mac-email**


**6
Son
son-email**


**7
Son
son-email**




Changing 1 to 2 isn't really a "paradigm shift" here.
